# Flow: resolving modules in a monorepo that uses Yarn workspaces

Tags: flowtype, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

We have a monorepo that uses [Yarn’s ‘workspaces’ feature](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/), meaning that whenever possible, Yarn will hoist dependencies to the monorepo's root `node_modules` directory rather than keep them in the individual package's `node_modules` dir. This relies on Node’s module resolving algorithm, which continues to search for modules in `node_modules` directories up the dir tree until it finds the required module.

When using Flow types in a file that imports another package (internal or external to the monorepo), running Flow inside the package that contains that file causes a `Cannot resolve <package-name>` error to be thrown. It seems like Flow uses a different module resolving algorithm, and fails since the installed modules are hoisted to the root dir and Flow does not continue to search up the dir tree.

Is there a way around this other than running Flow from the root? Running from the root is less than optimal because it does not allow different settings for different packages in the monorepo.

**Node version:** 10.8.0
**`flow-bin` version:** 0.78.0

Comment: Have you tried using flow's `module.system.node.resolve_dirname`  or `module.name_mapper` options?

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into this problem

To fix it need update `.flowconfig`:

```
[include]
../../node_modules/
```

FS struct:

```
/project_root
--/node_modules
--/packages
----/module1
------.flowconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick the components to be hoisted by hand with a directive like:

```
"nohoist": ["**/npm-package", "**/npm-package/**"]
```

or select them with an exclude glob:

```
"nohoist": [  
  "**/!(my-site|my-cms|someones-components)"
 ]
```

See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310476/yarn-workspaces-nohoist-exclude/65812081#65812081) for more information.