# Yarn workspaces: nohoist exclude

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

In my package.json, I currently have

```
"workspaces": {
  "nohoist": **
}
```

I would like to specify JUST TWO packages to hoist, and nohoist on everything else.  Is there a simple way to do this without pasting all of my packages except those two into `nohoist`?

Answer (score 5):

After days of digging I ended up with the following configuration.

Yarn seems to use some kind of [Bash glob pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) (see this [Linux journal article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) for a tutorial). In this configuration the `"nohoist"` rule disables hoisting for every module whose [virtual path](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/#glob-patterns-matching) ends with one of the strings in the list. Sadly Yarn interprets the string as a prefix so that also modules like "my-site-whatever" and "someones-components-whatever" match, but this can be dealt with.

```
{
  "private": true,
  "version": "independent",
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [ "packages/**/*" ],
    "nohoist": [  
      "**/!(my-site|my-cms|someones-components)"
     ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "yarn workspace @myscope/my-site link --link-folder $PWD/node_modules @someone/someones-components"
  }
}
```

I included in this example also a postinstall script which is out of topic but shows how we can establish a symbolic link to a sibling package after the dependencies have been installed. Upon install, Yarn Workspaces creates a symbolic link to each package in workspace root `/node_modules`. We can take an advantage of that and use one of those links to effortlessly create a wanted symlink in a package, by pointing `yarn link`'s `--link-folder` parameter to `/node_modules` at the workspace root.

This assumes that `@myscope/my-site/package.json` has a declared dependency on `@someone/someones-components`. That dependency can be added with the command

```
yarn workspace @myscope/my-site add @someone/someones-components
```

Because `@someone/someones-components` is configured for hoisting in our workspace root `package.json`, it is at Yarn's discretion to install it in `/node_modules` at the workspace root, not under the package private `node_modules`. Also, if `@someone/someones-components` has been downloaded into `/packages/@someone/someones-components`, it is matched by our `packages` directive `"packages/**/*"` and not downloaded into `/node_modules` either, but rather symlinked like so:

```
/node_modules/@someone/someones-components -> ../../packages/@someone/someones-components
```

Which is perfect. The only thing we need to do is to keep the postinstall script up to date to have required symlinks available in dependent packages. I think we could also automatically look up the dependencies in the script and establish the links.

Search keywords: monorepo lerna (not needed)

Comment: I still ended up in trouble because linking is buggy in that configuration and Yarn didn't add the dependency as a development dependency but as a production dependency an then complained about the error it made. I think this could be worked around by editing the dependencies in package.json directly, but I gave up.